# How to split string based on multiple Keywords?

Tags: c#

I have a string which has string values separated by special character ';' and I need to split string and store each value in separate string. In my ipStr, keywords like ServerName, DBName, TableNames and ColumnNames are identifiers and it will not change only the values might get changed.

For Example.

```
string ipStr = "ServerName=DevTestServer;DBName=CustomerSummary;TableNames=CustomerDetails&OrderDetails;ColumnNames=ID,CustName,OrderID;"
```

Now I want to split ServerName, DBName, TableNames and ColumnNames values separately and store each value in in different strings. I tried below but after finding ServerName, identifying DBName part looks difficult and also it does not look like a proper way of coding.

```
string ServerIdentifier = "ServerName=";
string separator = ";";
string serverName = ipStr.Substring(ipStr.IndexOf(ServerIdentifier), ipStr.IndexOf(delimiter));
```

What is the easiest way of getting values like below from the ipStr.

```
string ServerName="DevTestServer";
string DBName="CustomerSummary";
string TableNames="CustomerDetails&OrderDetails";
string ColumnNames="ID,CustName,OrderID";
```

Comment: Use IndexOf and store splitted string in each variable.

Comment: do a search for ConnectionStringBuilder - might be useful here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` won't work because `ServerName` etc isn't a valid token in a connection string.

However, a low tech approach is to use a good old fashioned `Split` and `ToDictionary`

```
var someWeirdStr = "ServerName=DevTestServer;DBName=CustomerSummary;TableNames=CustomerDetails&OrderDetails;ColumnNames=ID,CustName,OrderID;";

var results = someWeirdStr
   .Split(';',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(x => x.Split('='))
   .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x.ElementAtOrDefault(1));

Console.WriteLine(results["ServerName"]);
Console.WriteLine(results["DBName"]);
Console.WriteLine(results["TableNames"]);
Console.WriteLine(results["ColumnNames"]);
```

**Output**

```
DevTestServer
CustomerSummary
CustomerDetails&OrderDetails
ID,CustName,OrderID
```

Comment: This is going to break after the split by semi colon, you need to remove empty strings at that point.

Comment: @TheGeneral - StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is showing error. Cannot convert from StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to char.

Comment: @Ask_SO try `.Split(new char[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` if you are using an older version of .net

Answer (score 1):

you need to split the string by semi colon and then remove any empty strings then, after that you can split again by equals and create a dictionary of the results.

```
string ipStr = "ServerName=DevTestServer;DBName=CustomerSummary;TableNames=CustomerDetails&OrderDetails;ColumnNames=ID,CustName,OrderID;";
    
    var values = ipStr.Split(';')
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => {
            var pair = x.Split('=');
            return KeyValuePair.Create<string, string>(pair[0], pair[1]);
        })
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    foreach (var i in values) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i.Key}: {i.Value}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

```
string ipStr = "ServerName=DevTestServer;DBName=CustomerSummary;TableNames=CustomerDetails&OrderDetails;ColumnNames=ID,CustName,OrderID;";
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = Regex
                .Matches(ipStr, @"\s*(?<key>[^;=]+)\s*=\s*((?<value>[^'][^;]*)|'(?<value>[^']*)')")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["key"].Value,m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

result:

[image]